# Embed an Angular 2 app inside another Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, iframe, embed

I have been tasked to implement an angular 2 based application that
provides a header, navigation bar and a footer. All pretty standard stuff.
But in between the navigation bar, other angular 2 applications can be 
displayed, which application depends on user selection in the navigation
bar. 
The embedded Angular 2 applications are accessed through their own URL.
The navigation bar is constructed dynamically using results from a
REST API to allow easy configuration.

It sounds like this could be implemented using an IFRAME, but are there
any alternatives to using IFRAME's, and what happens with the navigation using the 
back and forth buttons of the browser, keyboard short-cuts, etcetera.

Can I adjust the IFRAME size dynamically to fit the size of the embedded
angular app? Even when the size of the embedded application changes?

Comment: I don't think there are alternatives. You might need to provide a custom `LocationStrategy` (based on the default `HashLocationStrategy` or `PathLocationStrategy`)

Comment: Thanks Günter, the LocationStrategy is meant for the navigation, but what about the IFRAME vertical size?
Preferably it the IFRAMEś vertical size needs to be adjusted according to the embedded contents.

Comment: You can communicate the size from the child to the parent and let the parent set the passed size.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds reasonable. It probably requires [cross document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
Thanks for showing the direction. I will share my findings here once completed or come back with further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding angular 2 app's, or anything else for the matter, can be achieved using IFrame's:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NavigationService} from "../navigation.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'framed-content',
    template: `
    <div class="row content application-box">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <iframe #iframe style="width: 100%;height: 100vh;position: relative;"
                [src]="selectedContent | safe"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
})
export class FramedContentComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

    private selectedContent = 'content/home.html';

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private navigationService: NavigationService) {
    }

    /**
     * Registers a callback for retrieving the target based on the selected content
     */
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.map(params => params['selectedItem']).subscribe((selectedItem) => {
            this.selectedContent = this.navigationService.getNavigationItem(selectedItem).target;
        })
    }
}
```

The only issue left is resizing the IFrame to fit the content.
That is solved using a piece of plain javascript in de main index.html of the container application:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.5">
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

        // IMPORTANT: Check the origin of the data!
        if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://localhost')) {
            // The data sent with postMessage is stored in event.data
            console.log(event.data);
            resize(event.data);
        } else {
            // The data hasn't been sent from your site!
            return;
        }
    });

    function resize(frameHeight) {
        console.log('Parent resize');
        frame=document.getElementById('loketFrame');
        console.log(frame);
        frame.height=frameHeight;
    }
</script>
```

Each time the embedded application changes its size, it needs to post a message to the container to update the iframe's height:

```
ngOnInit() {

  setTimeout(() => {
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    console.log('Resizing to ' + height);
    parent.postMessage(height, '*');

  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: The [IFrameResizer NPM module](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) automatically hadles resizing of IFrames based on its contents.

Comment: 's answer is totally accurate. Nice job but iframes are kludgey. A non-iframe way may be to export a module from one Angular app and imports it into the other. Maybe this answer will help anyone who has found their way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461338/how-to-embed-angular-app-inside-another-angular-app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it sounds promising but the situation become a little more complicated.
One of the teams decided to change the framework used to react combined with redux, so have them export an angular module will be difficult.