# How to embed Angular app inside another Angular app

Tags: angular

I have two Angular projects. One is called *App1*, and other is *Angular Form Editor*. I want to embed *Form Editor* into *App1* (project). How can I do this?

Comment: in Angular 2 you should use Angular 2 modules. If you want to build Angular 2 app into another Angular 2 app you can use the first Angular 2 app as an Angular 2 module and then import it in a second Angular 2 app

Comment: So I need first to create the FormEditor App as angular2 module in my App1 project?Any example please mentioned the link.

Comment: How are they supposed to communicate with each other?

Comment: Right now I want just to embed interface of form-editor into App1.After this I will right back-end for it.So it will communicate with each other.My requirement right is to use form-editor interface into App1.

Answer (score 1):

Build a module with App2.

This can be a complex task but there are plenty of templates out there you can use. I created this minimal module template - feel free to use it: https://github.com/angular-patterns/ng-module-template

Then create an app with App1 and import the App2 module. Make sure to declare the component from the App2 module.

```
import 'App2Module' from 'App2Module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [App2Module],
    declarations: [App2Component]
})
```

If you also need an app template, here is one:

https://github.com/angular-patterns/ng-app-template

It uses `@ngtools/webpack` for the AoT buld.