# Running two Angular applications completely separate in the same page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am currently working on an application that allows other Angular applications to be embedded into a main frame.

At the moment we are using IFrames as the mechanism for this and it all works completely fine but has some limitations.

I am trying to remove IFrames and embed another Angular application. I originally thought id be able to do this using something like Web Components and using a shadow DOM but I found that it only isolates the CSS and not the actual JavaScript.

So what I am asking is - Is it possible to run two completely seperate Angular applications in the same window? I am not talking about reusing the Angular lib, id like to be able to have different versions running.

So in theory it would work like this..

1. Load 'Shell' Application which is an Angular application
2. Separately load child application & all its libaries (angular, zone, rxjs etc)
3. Initialise all libraries and bootstrap Angular application into a container

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461338/how-to-embed-angular-app-inside-another-angular-app

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this will work or not coz I didn't tried it.

Here the link to the might be Solution
https://blog.sstorie.com/bootstrapping-multiple-angular-2-applications-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that reuses all the same version of the libraries and ensures they are not reloaded. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok Steoates. No problem.